# How to add Toggle Class to links with React.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, redux, array.prototype.map

I need to add toggle class active after clicking on the links has menu.

```
const AllLinksNavbar = Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll(".has-menu")
    )

    AllLinksNavbar.forEach( element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            element.classList.toggle('active')
        });
    } )
```

Comment: Can you please post the error?

Answer (score 0):

in react we work with states.
you need to create state with `const [className, setClassName] = useState("someClass");`
then you need to change this class by the function `setClassName`

```
onClick={()=>{ 
  if(className.includes("active")){
     setClassName(className.replace("active",""))
  } else {
     setClassName(className + " active")
  }
}}
```

then use this state as a class name for the element

```
<div className={className}> </div>
```